# How to extract a table of the acf values?

Tags: time-series

I'd like to extract a table of the acf values. 
I use this R command: 
acf(x, plot=FALSE) that gives me the values of the acf function. But I want it in a table format in order to copy in Word. 
Could somebody suggest me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the results of the `acf` function to an object and extract the values you're interested in. For instance using the monthly temperature data from Nottingham

```
d<-nottem
notts<-acf(d)
df<-data.frame(notts$acf,notts$lag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty excel file which I name **ACFEXCEL** on your pc note the directory as I have put in my pc name call **economia** in drive **C** on **Desktop** and then name your command with something I call **ACF* then write table as below

```
ACF <-acf(x, plot=FALSE)
write.table(ACF,"C:/Users/economia/Desktop/ACFEXCEL",col.names 
=FALSE,row.names = FALSE)
```

It will work